# Linking MouseEvent/MouseListener to ActionMap/InputMap binds in Java

Tags: java, events, mouseevent, key-bindings

I have what appears to be a somewhat unique problem. I'm currently trying to code mouse events into my program, a game engine of sorts. My problem is:

When the mouse is clicked/released, I want to evoke code that has already been written as an Action for the Enter key.

In my Binds class, I link enter to my action as such:

```
public class Binds extends InputMap
{
    public Binds(JPanel object)
    {
        // InputMap stuff
        InputMap inputMap = object.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0, false), "ESCAPE");
    }
}
```

With the corresponding ActionMap:

```
ActionMap actionMap = game.getActionMap(); //game is an object which extends JPanel.
actionMap.put("ENTER", new AbstractAction(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        //A very excessive amount of code    
    }
}
```

I do not want to copy-paste the code in the ActionMap, and would like to keep the code simple. Is there any way that I could link my MouseEvent/MouseListener such that it manually executes this code?

Two methods I have thought of, but can't implement include:

1. Adding MouseListener to the inputMap
2. Manually invoking the ActionMap code within the mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) method.

I have tried finding ways of doing both, but there seems to be no way of doing so. Also, I do not have ActionListeners in my code. I use them with my JButtons, but not my key bindings. If you need any additional information, please let me know.

What would I be able to do? Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the code to a private method:

```
private void doAction() {
    //A very excessive amount of code    
}
```

Then call that method from both your ActionMap and your MouseListener methods:

```
actionMap.put("ENTER",
    new AbstractAction() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            doAction();
        }
    });

gamePanel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
        doAction();
    }
});
```